# How do I keep a list using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 lists displayed on a page, Added and Available.  If you a record in the Available list, it's removed from that list and added to Added.  Ajax is used to refresh to display new results.  The following code makes this work, however.  I'm stumped as to how I can keep up with each list and make it persist.  Right now it only remembers based off the initial model data.  Any suggestions would be great 
I've worked hard on this (I'm still new).

**jquery ajax:**

```
<script>
    function AddProperty(propertyid) {
        var currentProperties = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Added));
        var availableProperties = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Avail));

        if (currentProperties.Id == null) {
            var x = {
                "Id": 0,
                "Name": "na",
                "Value": "na"
            };
            currentProperties.push(x);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AddProperty",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ PropertyId: propertyid, editList: currentProperties, availList: availableProperties }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#edittable tr").remove();
                $("#availtable tr").remove();
                for (var i = 0; i < result.FirstList.length; i++) {
                    if (result.FirstList[i].Id > 0) {
                        $('#edittable').append(
                            '<tr><td>'+result.FirstList[i].Name+':</td>' +
                           '<td><input type="text" id=editval"' + i+ '" value="'+result.FirstList[i].Value+'"></td>' +
                           '<td>' +
                               '<a class="btn-primary" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="DeleteProperty('+result.FirstList[i].Id+')" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" /></a>' +
                        '</td></tr>'
                        );
                    } else {
                        $('#edittable').append('<tr><td>No configuration values added.</td></tr>');
                    }
                }                    

                for (i = 0; i < result.SecondList.length; i++) {
                    if (result.SecondList[i].Id > 0) {
                        $('#availtable').append(
                            '<tr><td><a class="btn-primary" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AddProperty('+result.SecondList[i].Id+')" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" /></a></td>' +
                            '<td>'+result.SecondList[i].Name+':</td>' +
                            '</td></tr>'
                        );
                    } else {
                        $('#availtable').append('<tr><td>No configuration values available.</td></tr>');
                    }
                }  
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('error: ' + thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Viewmodel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public List<Children> Added { get; set; }
    public List<Children> Avail { get; set; }
}

public class Children
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProperty(int propertyId, List<Children> editList, List<Children> availList)
{
    var newEditList = new List<Children>();

    //add object to added list
    var newEditRow = availList.Where(edit => edit.Id == propertyId).ToList();
    newEditList.AddRange(newEditRow);

    //remove from available list
    var newAvailList = availList.Where(avail => avail.Id != propertyId).ToList();

    var result = new { FirstList = newEditList, SecondList = newAvailList };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View code:**

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div class="panel panel-primary" id="ConfigValueContainer">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2>Our Values</h2>
        <hr />
    </div>
       <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="lineup-tables">
           <h3>Edit Values</h3>
           <table id="edittable">
               @*<tr>
                   <td colspan="2">Message Type: @Model.Desc</td>
               </tr>*@
               @if (@Model.Added.Any())
               {
                   foreach (var added in Model.Added)
                   {
                       <tr>
                           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => added.Name):</td>
                           <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => added.Value)</td>
                           <td>
                               <a class='btn-primary' style='cursor:pointer' onclick='DeleteProperty(@added.Id)' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' /></a>
                           </td>                  
                       </tr>
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   <tr>
                       <td>No configuration values added.</td>
                   </tr>
               }
           </table>
       </div>
           <div class="lineup-tables">
           <h3>Add New Values</h3>
               <table id="availtable">
                   @if (@Model.Avail.Any())
                   {
                       foreach (var avail in Model.Avail)
                       {
                           <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a class='btn-primary' style='cursor:pointer' onclick='AddProperty(avail.Id)' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign' /></a>
                                </td>  
                               <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => avail.Name)</td>
                           </tr>
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       <tr>
                       <td>No configuration values available.</td>
                   </tr>
                   }
               </table>
               </div>
           <br/>
           <div class="panel-footer">
               <input type="submit" disabled class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
               <span id="close" class="btn btn-primary cancelLink">Cancel</span>

               <div class="clearfix"></div>
           </div>

       </div>
       </div>
}
```

Comment: Elaborate what you mean by "persist" a little more. Do you mean when you leave this page and come back you want it to be the same as when you left?

Comment: @JB06, no, not at all.  I mean when I click the button it adds to the list.  Then I can send each list to the controller for manipulation again.  Right now when the AddProperty function is clicked it automatically assigns current and available properties to model data (which hasn't changed).

Comment: Ah I see. What I would do is create two arrays using jquery by selecting the elements that contain the items. Could you post your view code in the question?

Comment: Added view code.  So just select the items within each table?  EditArray = edittable contents, AvailArray = availtable contents?

Comment: Yes. You will have to manipulate them and create objects that MVC will be able to map back to your model objects in the controller though.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  I get the array part, I'm working on that now.

Comment: I'm working on an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add hidden inputs to each table row to make it easy to grab everything you need.

```
#edittable 
<tr> 
  <input type="hidden" class="id" value="@added.Id" />
  <input type="hidden" class="name" value="@added.Name" />
  <input type="hidden" class="value" value="@added.Value" />

  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => added.Name):</td> 
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => added.Value)</td> 
  <td> 
    <a class='btn-primary' style='cursor:pointer' onclick='DeleteProperty(@added.Id)' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' /></a> 
  </td>                   
</tr> 

#availtable 
<tr> 
   <input type="hidden" class="id" value="@avail.Id" />
   <input type="hidden" class="name" value="@avail.Name" />
   <input type="hidden" class="value" value="@avail.Value" />

   <td> 
     <a class='btn-primary' style='cursor:pointer' onclick='AddProperty(avail.Id)' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign' /></a> 
   </td>   
   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => avail.Name)</td> 
</tr>
```

Now, instead of using currentProperties and availableProperties the way you do, try this:

```
function AddProperty(propertyid) {
  var currentProperties = [];
  var availableProperties = [];

  $('#edittable tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var child = {
      Id: row.find('.id').val(),
      Name: row.find('.name').val(),
      Value: row.find('.value').val()
    };
    currentProperties.push(child);
  });

  $('#availtable tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var child = {
      Id: row.find('.id').val(),
      Name: row.find('.name').val(),
      Value: row.find('.value').val()
    };
    availableProperties.push(child);
  });

  // Use them in your ajax call
```

This may need some tweaking, but should get you going on the right path.

Comment: This is good stuff.  I'll get to work on this and let you know how it fares.  Much thanks!